How to neutralize iron magnetism?

After welding the 3 welding ends of the pipe, a very high magnetic intensity has been created in the fourth welding end, which does not allow me to weld that part. I made many attempts to neutralize the magnetic state, but unsuccessfully. How can I remove the magnetization from the tube?
One of the attempts is to wrap the cable around the pipe (the magnetized part) and connect the end of the cable to the positive and negative sockets and vice versa.

"I made many attempts to neutralize the magnetic state, but unsuccessfully." Please explain what you've tried so that answers don't simply repeat them.

Can you explain how magnetisation of the pipe prevents welding ?

Due to the adhesion of the electrode or tungsten to the pipe, it is not possible to weld in the best possible way. This steam inlet pipeline to the turbine has a pressure of about 600 bar

Have to say I disagree with the close votes. The question is, if you have magnetized iron, how do you demagnetize it. The question is clear and answerable with or without knowing what was tried already and what technical issue this person is having with welding in the presence of magnetization.

Due to the creation of a magnetic field, it is not possible to melt and weld in that part, and it fails 100% in the radiographic test.

Most ferromagnetic materials can be demagnetized by heating them up hot enough: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curie_temperature
For iron, 770 C should be hot enough. If you're working with some other material, check the table in the linked article to see how much to heat it up.

So magnetism might make it hard to stick parts together just like you want. But If you start welding, the magnetism will be gone. However, if there are magnets nearby, it may come back. Cooling hot metal next to a magnet is how you make a magnet.
